# Does UK rail station's ticket machine sell group tickets?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

Does UK rail station's ticket machine sell group tickets?

Also, does the ticket machine runs 24 hours?

Edit: I am asking for the station of Cambridge.

Comment: Which station? Different stations can have different kinds of ticket machines, with different hours and different tickets sold / not sold...

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks. I am asking for Cambridge station

Comment: Cambridge has a manned ticket office [that's open virtually the whole day](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations/CBG/details.aspx). Why worry about ticket machines when you can just speak to a friendly human who'll sell you exactly the right ticket?

Comment: @Gagravarr waiting times maybe? Often the ticket windows have a much longer waiting time.

Comment: Since the development and the opening of the new ticket hall a few months back, I've found the waiting times to be comparable.  If noone else answers this by tomorrow, I'll nip down to the station and find out.

Comment: @Gagravarr Cambridge's ticket office only opens Monday - Friday 05:10 - 23:00, according to your link. Not 24 hours :P

Comment: @Gagravarr When I can buy a ticket from a machine I usually much prefer it. As a regular user I find it to be much faster, and any mistakes made will be my fault rather than out of my control (or to put it another way, there's one fewer human to introduce human error). While I've never experienced Cambridge, many ticket office humans are also far from friendly! (Though I think the unfriendly ones are still the exception rather than the rule). I think it's a shame that ticket offices are closing, but frankly when I can, I buy from machines, as it's faster and more reliable for me.

Comment: @zlin I never said it was 24 hours! It's open virtually the whole time that there are trains running, which is pretty much what matters

Answer (score 6):

OK, the official answer from the staff at Cambridge station is "yes, you can buy a GroupSave ticket from the machines".  I tried buying a GroupSave (GS) return to Ely.  It isn't straightforward.

Firstly, simply telling it you have three people isn't enough, you have to press "Railcards" to access the GroupSave option.  Secondly, although the machine says the ticket is valid on all services, according to the staff it is lying, and GS tickets CBG-ELY are not valid on Cross Country services (ie, those that are going to/from Birmingham).  Similar issues arise with many other GS tickets.

As for hours, the ticket machines are accessible "all the hours the station is open", which is from shortly before the first train to shortly after the last one.  According to my helpful staff member, this is **roughly** 0400-0115, which is a wider set of hours than those for which the ticket office is open

As another caveat, if you try to buy tickets after midnight and before the station shuts, the machines will try to sell you a ticket for the day that has just passed (because tickets for day X are valid until the small hours of day X+1); you have to buy a ticket for "tomorrow" to get one valid for the actual day in which you find yourself.  But by 0400 the machines have often caught on, so if you then ask for a "tomorrow" ticket out of force of habit, you will get one for the following day.

In short, the advice of the (super-friendly and helpful) staff member is "don't buy GroupSave tickets from the machines, come to us".  But if you really want to, then that is how and when you can do it.  You *might* also want to try buying them in advance via National Rail Enquiries, and just collect them from the machine; apparently NRE *does* know which trains GS tickets are valid on.

Comment: Tickets for one day are usually valid until 0429 the following day, so maybe that's the logic of selling the "wrong" day. [e.g., "Outward Validity: Day  - DATE ON TICKET UNTIL 0429 THE NEXT MORNING"](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=CBG&dest=ELY&rlc=GS3&tkt=CDR)

Comment: I think that is exactly the point, and I am grateful to you for putting it much more clearly than I did!

Comment: Except there isn't much logic there because a ticket is still valid FROM 0000 that day, so you're paying the same for (*much*) less validity.

Comment: @MadHatter at least making it really hard to sell you one is (probably) better than what SWT machines used to do - sell you one really easily by accident whenever you select 3 people without telling you it isn't valid on CrossCountry! (Though there's a perfectly reasonable argument that if you weren't told it isn't valid on CrossCountry you should be able to use it on CrossCountry without penalty).

Comment: "Secondly, although the machine says the ticket is valid on all services ...": In the [GroupSave ticket I found](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=CBG&dest=ELY&rlc=GS3&tkt=CDR), it has Route: **Any Permitted**. Trains that go from A to B directly are always "a permitted route", I believe, and therefore it seems to me that the ticket is valid on those CrossCountry services according to the National Conditions of Carriage. Maybe a rail enthusiast can show why I am wrong. I do notice that CrossCountry services are excluded in the "Unpublished Restrictions" for that ticket ...

Comment: ... but my understanding was that the "Unpublished Restrictions" were simply a mechanism to optimise computer timetable searches, and did not have legal effect. If CrossCountry were not allowed, the Route should say "NOT CROSSCOUNTRY". I could certainly be wrong, so I would be interested to hear what the answer is!

Comment: @Calchas well, you're welcome to go to the station and ask.  There's only one of me, so I have a strictly limited interest in the question (my secret train spod indulges himself in finding the *cheapest* outside-boundary-zone-6 destination to which I can buy off-peak returns from Cambridge, since these do not suffer from the evening departure restrictions that OPRs to London termini do).

Comment: @Calchas I suspect GroupSave tickets count as promotional tickets. The official page saying which TOCs they are available on is here: http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/pr354fdc0a0400020101fea1769fbf60.aspx . I don't know if the framework for this sort of restriction exists in the Conditions of Travel though. I agree that it's very confusing.

Comment: @Calchas covered under this maybe? But that seems to be contradicted by 13.3, which seems to say that such restrictions must be explicitly printed on the ticket. `13.1 Some Tickets, particularly advance Tickets, require you to travel on a specific
 train service or services, or the services of a particular Train Company or
 Companies. We will make these conditions clear to you when you purchase
 your Ticket.`

Comment: @Muzer umm, that doesn't say anything about the restrictions being *printed* on the ticket; only that they must be brought to your attention when you purchase it.

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry, I wasn't clear, as I was referencing 13.3 but quoting 13.1. 13.3 says: `13.3 Your Ticket may show that it is valid only on certain train services, such as
 those of a particular Train Company, or on trains travelling via a certain route
 or routes. If no specific route or Train Company is shown, then (subject to
 any time restrictions for the type of fare you have purchased) it will be valid
 on: ` (then a list of the ways to determine permitted routes).

Comment: @Muzer OK, thanks, but that *still* doesn't say that if a ticket is service-restricted, that it *must* say so.  It merely says that if it *does* say so, then it *is* restricted, and if it *doesn't* say so, then (see list of ways to determine restriction).  May I say in passing that I think this is an appalling state of affairs, and were I the rail regulator I'd simply enforce flat ticket policies across the UK (standard off-peak hours, etc.)?  But I think we have to be clear about what it is while condemning it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57411/discussion-between-muzer-and-madhatter).